# As a User how to move some email from Gmail to Office365?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, office-365, migrate-data

I have some mail in my Gmail account that is tagged with a certain tag, and I want to move this to a office 365 email account. How Do I do this?

*Background*: An organization that I'm involved with, earlier had their mail configured with a third party provider, and I was using Gmail's POP3 access to get it into my Gmail account. I also have a filter which applied a tag to all such emails.

This organization has now moved to office365, and I would like all their emails which are right now in my Gmail, to be moved to my office 365 folders.

I'm a regular user of office 365, and do not have admin access to this organization's office 365 console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Both these services support IMAP, it's possible to use an IMAP client to migrate mails from one to the other.

If you want a GUI application, you could use Thunderbird or Outlook, and connect both the mail accounts. you can then drag and drop the messages from one folder to the other. Do note that your client will download the mails first, and then upload it to the target service. This can take a fair bit of time, depending on your internet connection.

If you prefer, you could also use a command line tool such as https://github.com/jarus/imap_copy which can be preferable if you are a programmer, or techncical enough.